# How to properly augment Express types?

Tags: typescript, express

I have a file: `types/express.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Response {
    respondWith(data: any): Response;
  }
}
```

and this in `app.js`

```
Express.response.respondWith = function(data) {
  return this.json({
    errors: null,
    data: data
  });
};
```

How can I properly combine these two files into one "augmentation"?

[I tried copying this almost identically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). But it doesn't seem to work.

[Here's a codesandbox attempt at augmentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmo43oj29x?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just learning TypeScript myself, so there is probably some place for improvement in this answer, but here it is:

I think you need to do the augmentation from `express-serve-static-core`, not `express` ( at least I could not make it work).

The other thing is that I do not know any other way of augmenting `express` than exporting it back from `express-formater`. According to TypeScript [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html), `express-formater` is a module plugin, so I was looking at `moment-range` for a suitable pattern to use here, but without success.

The relevant code:

`express-formater.ts`

```
import core from "express-serve-static-core";
import express from "express";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  export interface Response {
    respondWith: (p1: any) => Response;
  }
}

express.response.respondWith = function(data: string) {
  return this.json({
    error: null,
    data: data
  });
};

export default express;
```

The main `index.ts`:

```
import express from "./express-formater";

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.respondWith({ ok: true }) );

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Typescript app listening on port ${port}!`)
);
```

The updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q97rp367p6?fontsize=14). `tsconfig.json`needs `"esModuleInterop": true`.

**UPDATE**

Just re-checked that it is not necessary to export `express` back from `express-formater`. Just as a reminder to myself, an improved approach:

`express-formater.ts`

```
import core from "express-serve-static-core";
import express from "express";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  export interface Response {
    respondWith: (p1: any) => Response;
  }
}

express.response.respondWith = function(data: string) {
  return this.json({
    error: null,
    data: data
  });
};
```

The main `index.ts`:

```
import express from "express"
import "./express-formater";

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.respondWith({ ok: true }) );

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Typescript app listening on port ${port}!`)
);
```

Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q97rp367p6?fontsize=14).

Comment: it ended up being fairly simple. Definitely needed to augment express-serve-static-core.